# UICollectionViewController footer not re-positioning itself properly after endEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a simple UICollectionViewController that is one section with a header and footer pinned to visible bounds. When I click a textField in the footer, the footer automatically animates above the keyboard and the collectionView scrolls to show the cells that otherwise would have been hidden by the keyboard as you would expect. However, when I click one outside of the keyboard, and dismiss it with a call to `self.view.endEditing(true)` the footer and collectionView do not react unless the collectionView is scrolled near the bottom. If the collectionView is scrolled near the bottom, the footer and collectionView animate as expected.

How can I force the footer and collectionView to animate properly every time?

In the images below, the header is orange, footer is green, and there are 10 cells that alternate red and blue.

Actual Behavior (occurs when you are not scrolled near the bottom of the collectionView when the keyboard dismisses)
[image: actual behavior]

Desired Behavior (occurs when you are scrolled at or near the bottom of the collectionView when the keyboard dismisses)
[image: desired behavior]

I know there are some methods to achieve this with Notifications when the keyboard appears and disappears but I would prefer to just use the default UICollectionViewController behavior if possible. Is there some configuration or setting I am missing?

Code:
New Single View App. Delete StoryBoard and ViewController.swift. Delete the main storyboard entry from the info plist file.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = CollectionViewController.init()

    return true
}
}
```

CollectionViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
private let collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier = "MyHeaderFooterClass"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

init() {
    let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
    collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    super.init(collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.collectionView?.register(MyHeaderFooterClass.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier)
    self.collectionView?.register(MyHeaderFooterClass.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier)

    self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    self.collectionView?.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView?.delegate = self
}
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate
extension CollectionViewController {
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        self.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
extension CollectionViewController {
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    switch indexPath.row % 2 {
    case 0:
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    case 1:
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    default:
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    }
    else { //footer
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

    return view
}
}

// MARK: - Collection View Flow Layout Delegate
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
}
}
```

MyHeaderFooterClass

```
import UIKit

class MyHeaderFooterClass: UICollectionReusableView {
let textField: UITextField = {
    let view = UITextField.init()
    view.placeholder = "enter text here"
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.addSubview(textField)
    self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}

override func updateConstraints() {
    textFieldConstraints()
    super.updateConstraints()
}

private func textFieldConstraints() {
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: Did you see the answer I posted?

Comment: Hey sorry, yes I did. That did fix the issue of the footer stuck in the middle of the page but the cells themselves did not slide back down to match it. So I had to implement a different mechanism regardless. I appreciate your help and you did answer the original question so I will accept your answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

> **func layoutIfNeeded()**
>
> Use this method to force the view to update its **layout** immediately.
>
> **func invalidateLayout()**
>
> This method invalidates the **layout of the collection view** itself and
> returns right away.

**Solution:**

Looking at your code, you are already updating `collectionViewLayout`. So, you don't need to force update `collectionView` again. Therefore, simply removing <strike>self.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()</strike> alone will solve your issue.

Change your code as below:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        //self.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```